# Use map or list to store objects that should be accessed by object’s property?

Tags: java

I want to implement a book repository where books can be added, removed and updated. Books in this repository should be accessed by their ISBN which is an object property.

Should I use a list or a map? If a map is to be used, how do I get the key and value’s property to remain in sync?

Comment: I hope the ISBN number unique, if it is then use a Map with key as ISBN number and value as corresponding Book instance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to use an `HashMap` in the book repository. When I want to add a book to the repository, I'm going to add a copy of that book instead of a reference, so it cannot be modified outside of the repository. The same applies to to updating and getting a book.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class BookRepository {

    private Map<String, Book> books;

    public BookRepository() {
        this.books = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Book get(String isbn) {
        Book copy = null;

        if (this.books.containsKey(isbn))
            copy = new Book(this.books.get(isbn));

        return copy;
    }

    public boolean add(Book book) {
        Book copy = new Book(book);
        return this.books.putIfAbsent(copy.getIsbn(), copy) == null;
    }

    public boolean remove(String isbn) {
        return this.books.remove(isbn) != null;
    }

    public boolean update(Book book) {
        Book copy = new Book(book);
        return this.books.computeIfPresent(copy.getIsbn(), (isbn, existing) -> copy) != null;
    }

    public List<Book> getAll() {
        List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Book book : this.books.values())
            list.add(new Book(book));

        return list;
    }

    public void removeAll() {
        this.books.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arraylist like this:

```
ArrayList<Book> myBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

- After you add the book objects you can easily retrieve them by their properties

Example:

```
for(int i=0; i < myBooks.length; i++){
   if(myBooks[i].getISBN().equals("Specific ISBN that you want to look for")){
      // enter code here
   }

}
```

Please note that you need the getter method for the ISBN number in the Book class

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A Map would help like this

```
Map<String, Book> bookMap = new HashMap<String, Book>();
bookMap.put(book1.getIsbn(), book1);
bookMap.put(book2.getIsbn(), book2);
bookMap.put(book3.getIsbn(), book3);
bookMap.put(book4.getIsbn(), book4);
```

Give the key get the `Book`.

Answer (score 0):

A map seems like a way to go because it will take care of collection search for you. If you will look for books by isbn, I would suggest using a Map because its search has O(1) performance, while searching through a List has O(n) meaning that for large number of books, a Map will perform better.

On the other hand if you, for some reason, go with the List implementation (maybe you need linear data representation, or you need to know the order in which Book objects where added) then I would suggest that you also look in to the [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) Collection implementation because it will help you deal with duplicates.

Also, please keep in mind that this will store data *temporally*, meaning that all data will be lost when the program terminates. If you need your data to stay intact you should look into **persisting** data with Java - storing data to files, having a data base or even sending it a Web servise that will keep you data.

The most flexible solution is to have a peace of code that handles the logic of selecting what storage type you (or your user) need. That could be achieved by using an interface that has all the methods you need (like read, update, delete) and separate classes that implement that interface.

Below is an example Interface and 2 implementations, one for Map and one for a database(mock only)

Interface:

```
public interface IBookRepository{
    boolean addBook(Book book);
    void removeBook(Book book);
    void removeBookWithIsbn(String isbn);
    void editBook(Book bookWithNewProperties);
    void editBookTitle(String isbn, String title);
}
```

Map implementation:

```
public MapBookRepository() implements IBookRepository{

    private HashMap<String, Book> mBookMap;

    public MapBookRepository(){
        this.mBookMap = new HashMap<String, Book>();
    }

    public boolean addBook(Book book){
        if(!mBookMap.containsKey(book.isbn)){
            return mBookMap.put(book.isbn, book);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void removeBook(Book book){
        RemoveBookWithIsbn(book.isbn);
    }

    public void removeBookWithIsbn(String isbn){
        if(mBookMap.containsKey(book.isbn)){
            remove(book.isbn);
        }
    }

    public void editBook(Book bookWithNewProperties){
        removeBookWithIsbn(bookWithNewProperties.isbn);
        addBook(bookWithNewProperties);
    }

    public void editBookTitle(String isbn, String title){
        if(mBookMap.containsKey(isbn)){
            mBookMap.get(isbn).setTitle(title); // You need a setter in your Book Class
        }
    }
}
```

Data base implementation (only mock..):

```
public DbBookRepository() implements IBookRepository{
    public DbBookRepository(){
        // Db stuff
    }

    public boolean addBook(Book book){
        // Db stuff
    }

    public void removeBook(Book book){
        // Db stuff
    }

    public void removeBookWithIsbn(String isbn){
        // Db stuff
    }

    public void editBook(Book bookWithNewProperties){
        // Db stuff
    }

    public void editBookTitle(String isbn, String title){
        // Db stuff
    }
}
```

Use example could be:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    if(args.length != 1){
        return; 
    }

    IBookRepository repo;
    if(args[0].equal("DB")){
        repo = new DbBookRepository();
    }else if (args[0].equal("Map")){
        repo = new MapBookRepository();
    }else{
        return;
    }

    repo.addBook(new Book("a", "b", "c", 1.0));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use getter and setter method in your pojo class to achieve this.

```
ArrayList<Book> books=new ArrayList<Book>(0);
```

For insertion

```
books.add(book1);
```

Here book1 is a Book class object

For Updation

```
book1.getBookName(book1.setBookName("name"));
```

For Deletion

```
books.remove(1);
```

There remove takes the index value of book object